# Codesign .app game for Mac Apple Store, after the creation of the PKG and the verification of the installation, the game does not start

Tags: codesign

I would like to ask for advice.

I created a game in the .app format
For the Mac App Store I have to convert it to PKG in order to use the Application Loader and send it for verification.
I performed all signing procedures successfully with codesign -f -s "3rd Party Mac application installer".

Then I created the PKG file.
Everything seems to have gone the right way, even the PKG installation check is correct.
The problem occurs when once installed in / Application I want to test the opening.
The game does not start, it closes immediately.

How can I do?

The strange thing that I noticed that the terminal had returned me "support macOS system: 10.9"
How can I change the macOS support at least to 10.12?

Comment: check crash logs from xcode

Comment: hi Shauket,I exported from an external tool to .app and now I have to convert everything.
is an NWJS project, and the error is as follows:                                                              [0620/160545.927832:FATAL:child_port_handshake.cc(111)] Check failed: server_port.is_valid(). 
0   crashpad_handler                    0x0000000103971f5c crashpad_handler + 73564
1   crashpad_handler                    0x0000000103976f40 crashpad_handler + 94016
2   crashpad_handler                    0x00000001039913bd crashpad_handler +

Comment: are you using socket programming? server_port.is_valid()

Comment: Hi, it's an external program that creates a distribution package for Mac Osx.
It's RPG MV